# Using SharePoint CSS in Custom Web Part

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I created a Web part for Share Point in C#.net, and looking for the solution to use SharePoint's CSS in my web part rather than applying of my own, actually what i am looking for is if the Share Point theme is changed to Red, Blue etc, my custom web part should also look according to that, and I think it is only possible if I use Share Point CSS.

Any Idea, Will appreciate!

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have answered your own question. certainly you should use the CSS elements provided by sharepoint.

if you are looking for which elements to use and where following article is very good reference point and its for MOSS if you are looking for sharepoint 2010 just google it

http://www.heathersolomon.com/content/sp07cssreference.htm